Filter revenue by event in gtag




 puchase => event all order

puchase_1=> event cash order
purchase_2 => event installment order
I send event data to gtag with (purchase and purchase_1 and purchanse_2).
Why the total revenue is not changing?
I want detect which

How much purchase revenue ?
How much purchase_1 revenue?
Is it possible?

